# Logo de meta Stack Overflow en español en panel lateral de SEDE está equivocado

Tags: bug, estado-completado, data-explorer

En Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE), en lugar de mostrarse el logo de Stack Overflow Meta en Español en el panel lateral y las páginas de query, se muestra el que corresponde a portugués.

Pasos para reproducir

1. Ir a http://data.stackexchange.com/
2. Hacer clic en **Stack Overflow Meta en español**
3. Se mostrará la [página de queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/esme/queries). A continuación un recorte, en el que se subrayó en rojo **em Português**

[image: panel lateral SEDE]

Comment: Parece que ya lo corrigieron

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: En la que es la página de meta.soes a mi me sigue apareciendo el logo de "Em portugês" ->http://data.stackexchange.com/esme/queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto se ha corregido. :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]